# How to target next element with class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion, slidetoggle

### DEMO

---

I am doing a simple jquery accordian effect as below.

**JQUERY**

```
$(function ($) {
  $('.Accordian').find('.Btn').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.Content').slideToggle('fast');
    $('.Content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Accordian">
  <div class="Btn"></div>
  <div class="Content"></div>
</div>
```

This work great however if content is placed between `.Btn` and `.Content` then it breaks.

---

**QUESTION**

1. How to directly target the next available class name relative to the
   button clicked?
2. How to target all elements of a class name **except** the next available
   class name relative to button clicked?

Comment: "*if content is placed between .Btn and .Content*" - i didn't get this part. Why would you want to put content outside `.Content`? can you clarify..?

Comment: I am not using accordian in traditional sense. I sometimes want to show some content all the time that is never hidden but needs to be below the button.

Comment: I added the comment before checking the fiddle. "elements" or "html content" would be more understandable instead of "content" since you already have such a div...

Comment: @Obsidion if you are trying to only target .Content and leave the 'breaking text' visible.. then WHY are you targeting it in the first place?

Comment: If your going to downvote at least have the decency to explain why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$(function ($) {
    $('.Accordian').find('.Btn').click(function () {
        //cache the value so that it can be used in the next statement
        var $content = $(this).siblings('.Content').slideToggle('fast');
        $('.Content').not($content).slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.nextAll()` along with `.first()` to accomplish your task, Actually here we have used `.first()` for a safety purpose.

```
  $('.Accordian').find('.Btn').click(function () {
    var targetElem = $(this).nextAll('.Content').first();
    targetElem.slideToggle('fast');
    $('.Content').not(targetElem).slideUp('fast');
  });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xHp9/2/)